# JS: Adding a space between Japanese character phrase and number using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need to add a space between all instances of the Japanese 丁目(*chome*) that are directly followed a number of unspecified digit length.

ex: 北23条東12**丁目5**-30-405

I have tried this (where s = "北23条東12丁目5-30-405")

`s.replace(/(?:丁目)+\d+/g, "$1 ")`

Since I want to add a space after a non-captured group, I thought a $1 was in order, but I am not sure how to write it (IF this replace method were to work it would probably literally output "$1 ").

Needless to say, my attempted replace() method does not work

(desired output: "北23条東12丁目 5-30-405")(<-- space after 丁目)

I'm not suprised this doesn't work... can I get pointed in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s.replace(/(丁目)(?=\d)/g, "$1 ")
```

This should do it for you.Your earlier regex was not working cos if `?:` which makes it non capturing and `$1` had nothing in it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/10

```
var re = /(丁目)(?=\d)/g; 
var str = '北23条東12丁目5-30-405';
var subst = '$1 '; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: It works :) 
Out of curiosity, is it safe to consider this second group (`(?=\d)`) as $2?
(I'm newbie)

Comment: @marzipan no it is a `lookahead`.If you want to capture `$2` use `(?=(\d+))`